# Where can you find out to whom a given Mac is registered?

Tags: macos

Is there a place in the OS that we can see to which person the OS is registered to?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The registration information that you enter when you setup OS X is stored in a hidden plist file in the system.

That data is stored the file /var/db/.AppleSetupDone if you run the following command in terminal you should be able to see that information:

```
sudo cat /var/db/.AppleSetupDone
```

This will show you the information entered. You will need to modify this information with a plist editor. For warranty claims Apple will know who registered the machine for AppleCare.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether the registration information is stored locally. If you call Apple, they can certainly tell you under which person the Mac is registered.